# Is it possible to use dnnModal.js to show a popup with content from its containing page?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use dnnModal.js to show a popup with content from its containing page, as opposed to content from an entirely separate URL?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is a pretty old question, it still goes for current DNN-versions (7.3.x) and I ran accross this posting because I had the exact same question.

The answer, sadly, is; no, this can't be done using the dnnModal-plugin.

You can however do it using [jQueryUI's own dialog-plugin](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). This is the same plugin DNN uses under the hood for dnnModal, so you don't need to reference any JS- or CSS-resources yourself. Be sure though, to ask DNN to reference jQuery and jQueryUI, through it's API, in your module.

For jQueryUI dialog to work correctly within DNN, without it conflicting with DNN's own styling, be sure to add the additional class "dnnFormPopup" to your dialog when initializing it, like so:
    $('div.dialog').dialog({
        title: 'This is your dialog's title',
        dialogClass: "dnnFormPopup"
    });

This is the same class DNN adds to the dialog when using dnnModal, and will make your dialog look exactly like a DNN-popup.

Comment: Any idea how to add the maximize/minimize button? I couldn't find any :(